# C# Console window, Escape Sequences Not Working

Tags: c#, console, ansi-escape

When I write code to write an escape sequence:
`Console.WriteLine("\x1b[94m Blue Text \x1b[0m");`

The code prints as:
`←[94m Blue Text ←[0m`

Does anyone know how this is caused? I am on .NET 6.0

I tried writing the escape sequence in a variable but this doesn't change anything. When I use `Console.Clear();` and rewrite the code with the same window it sometimes works.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you pop it in a .NET Framework x.y Console App?  I'm making a list of _who moved my cheese?_ ;)

Comment: There is no such thing as ".NET Framework 6.0". The last version of the .NET Framework was 4.8. .NET 5 and later are an evolution of .NET Core. .NET Core was built from the ground up so there are differences between it and .NET Framework. One important point is that any particular project template will only target .NET Framework or .NET Core, not both*. Those that target .NET Framework specifically say so in the template name. You are using .NET 6. We can work out what's going on this time but it's important to use the actual names of things to avoid confusion.